# undefined symbol: _open_osfhandle, handle to file descriptor, linking error

Tags: c, linux, linker-errors, handle

In a shared library I'm trying to convert a self created handle to a file descriptor so that I can run fsync on that file descriptor. I really have two questions, the first is bellow and the second is if there is some other way to get a file descriptor from a handle.

I include "#include " to my code and then call the code bellow:

```
int _open_osfhandle(intptr_t oshandle, int flags);
int fd = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)(handle), 0);

fsync(fd);
```

This compiles correctly but it does not work when I execute the code I get the following in the logs:

```
undefined symbol: _open_osfhandle
```

This usually means there is a linking error when creating the shared library but the correct libraries are linked while compiling the code. io.h is a part of:

```
rpm -qf /usr/include/sys/io.h
glibc-headers-2.17-105.el7.x86_64
```

Which should be the standard C library for redhat, which I Included in my ccmake build file:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -static-libgcc -pthread")
```

But I still get the error that the symbol is undefined.

I've tried to work around this by attempting to create my FD with the bellow command but I believe it did not work.

```
int fd = (uintptr_t)(handle);
```

Any ideas as to why this issue is coming up.

Also is there some other way for me to get a file descriptor from my created handle?

Comment: Libraries after object files?  You don't show the actual link command that is executed and failing, but a common cause of trouble is to list the libraries (`-lname`, etc) before the object files.  On some systems, that may work; on most, it does not.  List the libraries after the object files — that almost always works (and when it doesn't, there are extenuating circumstances, such as you forgot to list a library, or you listed the libraries in the wrong order, or …).

Comment: The [`_open_osfhandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdts1c9x.aspx) is a *Windows* specific function. Maybe you are looking for [`fdopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fdopen.3.html) or [`dup`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html)?

Comment: And what *is* the "handle" you try to "convert"? If it's a `FILE *` then just use [`fileno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fileno.3.html) to get the descriptor.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm not sure how I would use fdopen or dup for my needs since I do not have a file descriptor yet and both of those commands need it.

But fileno looks like what I need, my handle is not a FILE* but I can convert it to one and attempt to work with that. I'll update once I've tested.

Comment: Then what *do* you have? You say you have a "handle" but "handle" is a very generic term, even an integer file descriptor could be called a "handle". Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and more importantly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hey sorry about that I pressed enter and it posted without the full info I wanted to give.

@JonathanLeffler Since I'm using ccmake to build the make file I don't link via target link but add the definition of the static gcc library and link through the above command, I think. I'll check the order of my linking some more.